# Is there any way to generate multiple transpiled files using different configs with babel?

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, npm-scripts

I'm fairly new to both NPM scripts and Babel. I've used Gulp before but I'm trying to move towards Webpack + NPM scripts or even NPM only builds when Webpack isn't needed. This is one such example of the latter.

I would like to

- use my main ES6+ JS file `src/main.js`
- use babel to produce a fairly modern script file `docs/main.js` using a target like:

  > ```
  > browsers: [
  >        'Chrome >= 60',
  >        'Safari >= 10.1',
  >        'iOS >= 10.3',
  >        'Firefox >= 54',
  >        'Edge >= 15',
  > ],
  > ```
- use babel again to produce a more 'legacy' version of the scripts `docs/main.legacy.js` using a target like:

  > `"browsers": ["> 1%, not ie 11, not op_mini all"]`
- use npm scripts to create two build tasks out of this which I can later put into one command such as `npm run build`

After reading [Philip Walton's article](https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/) on creating multiple targets in his build process, I would like to know:

1. Is this possible with NPM scripts only if I don't need Webpack?
2. What is the recommended course of action to enable such functionality?

---

My attempts: `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "buildModern": "babel src/main.js -o docs/main.js -presets=env",
    "buildLegacy": "babel --no-babelrc src/main.js > docs/main.legacy.js",
    "build": "echo '=> Building Source Files' && buildModern && buildLegacy"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have multiple babel configs is to use [different environments in your `.babelrc` file](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc) (via the `env` option) and target them by setting the BABEL_ENV variable inside each of your NPM scripts.

A Babel-only approach will work well for transpiling individual JS files, but if you want to import other modules in your file and make it work in a browser, you will need a bundler such as Webpack or Rollup.

**Edit:** See Keno's write-up below.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I had to do a ton of research and experimentation but I finally got a config that worked smoothly for me.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! I'm sorry I could not provide more detailed guidance, I was on my phone in the backyard :)

Comment: Not a problem! You helped me to find the optimal path to solving it anyway 

Answer (score 3):

So for anyone who might stumble on this in the future wishing to do a similar thing, here's what I came up with. Kudos to Dan for the advice.

1. You'll need to create a `.babelrc` file and within it, use the `"env"` option which will contain as many environments as you want.
2. Set `BABEL_ENV=name` replacing `name` with one of the names specified in your config file.
3. Follow that up with your babel cli commands or whatever you want to do. E.g.

   ```
   cross-env BABEL_ENV=modern babel src/js/main.js -o docs/js/main.min.js && echo Building ES6+ Files...`
   ```
4. Make sure to install the necessary npm dependencies as needed. Hope this helps.

Here's an example of my config file

```
{
    "env": {
        "legacy": {
            "presets": [
                ["minify"],
                ["env", {
                    "targets": {
                        "browsers": ["> 1%, not ie 11, not op_mini all"]
                    }
                }]
            ]
        },
        "modern": {
            "presets": [
                ["minify"],
                ["env", {
                    "targets": {
                        "browsers": [
                            "Chrome >= 60",
                            "Safari >= 10.1",
                            "iOS >= 10.3",
                            "Firefox >= 54",
                            "Edge >= 15"
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly it!